# Unexpected stored procedure behaviour after database export

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to deploy a SQL Server 2008 R2 from my development environment hosted on a Virtual Box VM to a brand new test server. Both servers use integrated Windows authentication.

Part of the problem was that the test server uses SQL Server 2008 (Express). I have managed to export schema creation scripts and raw data inside an Access database, but this is not the subject of the question: apparently the database was correctly imported on the target environment.

However, when I started the web site that depends on the exported database, I got some errors that does not appear when running in the development environment. After some research I found that the problem is caused by a little stored procedure.

This stored procedure creates a table on the fly that is dropped when no longer needed with a syntax like this one:

```
create table tmp_Codes (Code nvarchar(max))
```

When the test environment executes this statement the test environment effectively creates the table but it has the username attached to it, something like:

```
dbo.[NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE].tmp_Codes
```

The subsequent code cannot find the newly created table and fails all operation on it.

I'll understand that this design is somehow broken, but I inherited this bunch of SQL scripts from a working environment and I cannot understand how this can work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was a very trivial error: the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE has the default schema set to its name instead of dbo.

After changing the setting, the stored procedure worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TABLE #tmp_Codes (Code nvarchar(max))

Comment: But the table created thus way will survive outside the procedure that creates it? Unfortunately the table is created inside a procedure then dropped in another.

Comment: Yes but the existing code do not drops it in the same procedure that creates it.